# Example of identically distributed process, not stationary

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Stationarity means, for every $B$, $$P((X_n)_{n\geqslant0}\in B)=P((X_{n+1})_{n\geqslant0}\in B)$$
Identical distribution means, for every $n$, $$P(X_0\in B)=P(X_n\in B)$$

> What would be an example of identically distributed process, not stationary?

Comment: IID is a sufficient condition for a process being stationary. So one can't find the example that you want.

Comment: Yes, this is what I interpreted from your question.

Comment: Try $X_0$ with a symmetric, non degenerate, distribution and $X_{4n}=X_{4n+1}=X_0$, $X_{4n+2}=X_{4n+3}=-X_0$, for every $n$. Then every $X_n$ has the distribution of $X_0$ while $(X_0,X_1)$ and $(X_1,X_2)$ have different distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Did.

Comment: @Did Could you check if I understood your example correctly? Since $X_0$ is symmetric, one example can be a Gaussian pdf. So, **1)** every $X_n$ has Gaussian distribution since changing the sign doesn't affect the pdf. ->this makes i.d.(identically distributed). And **2)** if one possible value(realization) of $X_0$ is $a$, then $X_0=X_1=a$ but $X_2=-a$ so it's _not_ a "stationary" random process. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: So... All "stationary random process" is identically distributed, but not vice versa?